# Template class specialization with a template template argument

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename T, typename ...L>
struct foo{};

template <typename T>
struct bar{
    using toto = T;
};

template <template<typename T, typename ...L> class F>
struct bar<F>{
    using toto = T
};

int main(){
    bar<foo<int,char,char>> a;
}
```

I want to specialize `bar`  when the argument is a class that has at least one template argument `<typename T, typename ...L>`

I tried :

```
template <template<typename T, typename ...L> class F>
struct bar<F<T,L...>>{
    using toto = T
};
```

and

```
template <template<typename , typename ...> class F, typename T, typename ...L>
struct bar<F<T,L...>>{
    using toto = T
};
```

which may have made sense, but I couldn't get it right

Comment: The last one looks like it should work. What was the error?

Comment: https://ideone.com/AQPIFy  , the problem is that bar takes only one template argument, but in order to call the last one, I need at least 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a lot of stuff on your sample, *syntactically* speaking

```
template <typename T, typename... L>
struct foo{};

template <typename T>
struct bar {
    using toto = T; // Semicolon missing
};

template <template<typename, typename...> class F, typename T, typename... L>
struct bar<F<T,L...>> { // Wrong pack expansion
    using toto = T;
};

int main() { // () missing

    bar< foo<int,char,char> > a; // Pass the parameters to foo since you're
                                 // partially specializing bar to just do that
}
```

<kbd>[Example on ideone](https://ideone.com/hWpnRC)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this, but I put `>>` before `a`, that is why it didn' t work

Comment: AFAIK It should work regardless of that space with newer C++ versions starting from C++11. Make sure you're using an up-to-date compiler

Answer (score 1):

Your ideone code just has a bunch of typographical errors:

```
struct bar<F<T,...L>>{
//should be
struct bar<F<T,L...>>{

//missing brackets
int main{

//missing semicolon
using toto = T

bar<foo, int,char,char> a;
//should be
bar<foo<int,char,char>> a;
```

Comment: because i've been medifying it, but it is still not workin

Comment: I tried this before, but now I see the issue, it' s the `>>`

Comment: That's a common parsing quirk of C++. Your compiler should issue a warning with the right options turned on, and C++11 adds a parsing rule to allow using `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few syntatic issues here.

1. `bar` is a template that takes one type argument. So any partial or explicit specialization of `bar` must also take one type argument.

   ```
   template <template<typename T, typename ...L> class F>
   struct bar<F> {
   ```

Here, the `T` and `L` names are irrelevent, and really you're specializating on a template template. That doesn't match. You'd have to specialize on a *specific* instantiation of `F`:

```
    template <template<typename , typename ...> class F,
        typename T, typename... L>
    struct bar<F<T, L...>> {
```

2. You're missing a semicolon:

   ```
   using toto = T;
                ^^
   ```
3. Your declaration of `main` is missing parentheses:

   ```
   int main() {
       bar<foo<int,char,char>> a;
   }
   ```